# HTML: Neither the image nor the alt-text is visible, border is visible

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, responsive-images

I developed a page with TOWeb, and copied it to a Bluehost site.  Some images aren't showing on Bluehost, and neither is the alt-text.  The border/outline around where the image should be is showing. (Images that don't use the code below work okay.) The images are there, and the file sizes match. The directory structure is the same.

```
<div class="pobj obj-before" style="text-align:center;">
<a href="_media/img/large/image-2.jpg" rel="trJu">
<img class=" frm-simple2"  src="data:image/gif;
base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" 
data-src="_media/img/small/image-2.jpg" 
data-srcset="_media/img/medium/image-2.jpg 1.6x,
_media/img/large/image-2.jpg 2.13x" style=
"max-width:100%;width:260px" alt="didn't load"></a></div>
```

Update:  The page loads correctly on my computer using the local Apache Server. (I have Windows 8). If I remove the 1x1px Transparent GIF image code  I see no difference locally, but on Bluehost there's now a box that's just large enough to display the alt-text, "didn't load."

Comment: when you click the `a` (anchor / link), does it work and display the image and what is shown in the URL bar?

Comment: Share your website's URL with us :)

Comment: Clicking on where the image should be loads the large version of the image on its own page.  In the TOWeb application, the large version of the image loads as an overlay on the same page, and you delete it by pressing an 'x.'

Comment: Hovering over where the image should be shows the URL http://mysite(dot)com/_media/img/large/image-2.jpg,

Comment: The page loads correctly on my computer using the local Apache Server.  (I have Windows 8).  If I remove the  1x1px Transparent GIF image I see no difference locally, but on Bluehost there's now a box that's just large enough to display the alt-text, "didn't load."